# Angular 7 move objects in array results in -1 index, will not save position

Tags: arrays, angular, move, angular7

So I'm working on a task board and I am making a button to move the selected task to the top/bottom of that container. It is working fine, but not saving the position and when I reload it is in the previous position. I noticed that when I am doing this, the array has a -1 index at the end. I've searched online for this issue but couldn't find anything similar.

Here is the code I have for the function:

```
public moveToBottom(container, index) {
this.container = container;
var lastIndex = (this.container.length -1);
this.loader.show();
transferArrayItem(this.container, this.container, index, lastIndex);

// this.verifyOrder(lastIndex);
this.loader.hide();
console.log(index, lastIndex, container)
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the container.length -1, but this is the only way I've seen to get the last index. I just need the number of the index, not the actual object.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is `container`?

Comment: It's the array all the tasks are held in

Comment: Oh, why do you use `transferArrayItem` on the same container? It has to be `moveItemInArray`.

Comment: I didn't even realize that was a thing haha. So I just tried changing it, but I'm still getting the -1 index at the end.

Comment: I'm using the CDK Drag Drop if that helps

Comment: Does it mean your `this.container.length` is zero?

Comment: No, the length of the container is 6 as it should be.

Comment: Can you show the transferArrayItem function?

Comment: @Wen Hao Wu, the transferArrayItem is a function that comes with Angular's drag/drop 
`export declare function transferArrayItem<T = any>(currentArray: T[], targetArray: T[], currentIndex: number, targetIndex: number): void;`

But here is the function

Comment: I quickly read through the tutorial on angular's drag/drop, don't you want to use the moveItemInArray function instead of the transferArrayItem function since you are moving the item within the same array?

Comment: Yeah I just tried that, but unfortunately it doesn't help. Thanks for trying to help though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use `transferArrayItem` function.

For example, there is an array of movies `this.movies`. 
So, the button click function will look like this:

```
moveToTheEnd(index) {
    moveItemInArray(this.movies, index, this.movies.length - 1);
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div *ngFor="let movie of movies; let index = index" style="display: flex; align-items: center">
      <div class="example-box"  cdkDrag>{{movie}}</div>
      <div (click)="moveToTheEnd(index)" style="background: red">Move to the end</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkwb8v

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped, I had the container.length-1 in a variable and for some reason wasn't liking it.